# HTML centering inline-block

Tags: html, css

I am trying to center text that is on top of an image but it seems no matter what I do it won't center it

I also attempted using margin 0 auto but that didn't help either.

```css
    #search_box {
     width: 100%;
     height: 450px;
     position: relative;
     text-align: center;
    }
    
    #search_box h1 { 
     display: inline-block;
     width: 50%;
     top: 180px;  
     color: white;
     background-color: red;
     position: absolute; 
    }
```

```html
<div id="search_box">
       <img src="images/background_search.jpg" alt="search_box_picture"/>
       <h1>SOME TEXT</h1>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

like this?

```css
#search_box {
    width: 100%;
    height: 450px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}

#search_box h1 { 
    display: block;
    width: 50%;
    top: 180px;  
    color: white;
    background-color: red;
  margin: auto;


}
```

```html
<div id="search_box">
            <h1>SOME TEXT</h1>
            <img src="images/background_search.jpg" alt="search_box_picture"/>
            
        </div>
```

Comment: Well the problem with that is then its not on top of the image itself

Comment: i edited the code. if you want to put the text on top of the image, just put the text first in your html before the image

Comment: i think he wants the image behind the text. is that right?

Comment: Yeah I want the text behind the image, but yeah his solution works too, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like this:-

```css
.image {
   position:relative;
   text-align:center;
  
}

.text {
    left: 0;
    position:absolute;
    top: 30px;
    width: 100%;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="image">
    <img src="http://davidrhysthomas.co.uk/img/dexter.png" />
    <div class="text">
       Text of variable length
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
#search_box {
     width: 100%;
     height: 450px;
     position: relative;
     text-align: center;
    }
    
    #search_box h1 { 
     display: inline-block;
     width: 50%;
     top: 180px;  
     color: white;
     background-color: red;
     position: absolute; 
        left:0; 
        right:0;
      margin:0 auto;
    }
```

```html
<div id="search_box">
       <img src="images/background_search.jpg" alt="search_box_picture"/>
       <h1>SOME TEXT</h1>
      </div>
```

Your image position is center according to parent div. H1 tag is not center aligned. you have to give left space to the absolute tag.

```css
#search_box {
     width: 100%;
     height: 450px;
     position: relative;
     text-align: center;
    }
    
    #search_box h1 { 
     display: inline-block;
     width: 50%;
     top: 180px;  
     color: white;
     background-color: red;
     position: absolute; 
        left:25%;
    }
```

```html
<div id="search_box">
       <img src="images/background_search.jpg" alt="search_box_picture"/>
       <h1>SOME TEXT</h1>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
    #search_box {
     width: 100%;
     height: 450px;
     position: relative;
     text-align: center;
    }
    
    #search_box h1 {
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 50%;
color: white;
background-color: red;
   
}
```

```html
<div id="search_box">
       <img src="images/background_search.jpg" alt="search_box_picture"/>
       <h1>SOME TEXT</h1>
      </div>
```

you want something like this?